# Value works, but not when passed via an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have this data:

```
[[1,7],[2,9],[3,5]]
```

That exists within a hidden input field like so:

```
<input id="chart-totals" type="hidden" value="[[1,7],[2,9],[3,5]]" />
```

Using this same data in the jqplot call works fine:

```
$.jqplot('data-totals',[[[1,7],[2,9],[3,5]]]);
```

However this doesn't:

```
var totals = $("#chart-totals").val();
$.jqplot('chart-totals',[totals]);
```

The square bracket situation seems odd to me. But I've tried every combination, so:

```
var totals = '['+$("#chart-totals").val()+']';
$.jqplot('chart-totals',totals);
```

etc.

But every time I get:

```
Uncaught Error: No data specified
```

Except for in the first example where the data is manually pasted into the call.

Any ideas? The data is identical, so there must be more to it…

Comment: $("#chart-totals").val() returns a string and it seems when you do $.jqplot('chart-totals',[[[1,7],[2,9],[3,5]]]); it is not passing a string. I don't know anything about jqplot but this seems odd to me

Comment: When your pulling the data from the input your retrieving a string, when your pasting it directly you are using an array.

Comment: same data, different types?

Comment: So how do I change its type?

Comment: are the input#chart-totals and the $.jqplot('chart-totals') elements sharing the same id, or does it just appear that way?

Comment: Good spot @nebulae - that was a typo in the question though :) I'll edit to reflect the accurate id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the string representation to an actual array:

```
var totals = JSON.parse($("#chart-totals").val());
$.jqplot('chart-totals', totals);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I did suspect it was something along these lines, but wasn't getting anywhere.

Comment: + to Jason P for being quick.